# Equalitiy of two multinormal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem proving the following thing: 
Consider a sequence of $r$ normal random variables $Z_j\sim N(0,1-p_j)$ (where $\sum_{i=1}^r p_i =1$) such that $E(Z_iZ_j)=-\sqrt{p_jp_i}$. 
On the hand we have $r$ iid standard normal $G_i$ which are defined as marginals of the multinormal $\mathbf{G}$ and we have the vector $\mathbf{p}$ such that
$$\mathbf{G}=(G_1,...,G_r) \quad and\quad \mathbf{p}=(\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_r})$$
Now considering the vector $\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{G}-(\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{p})\mathbf{p}$ we can easily prove that 
$$E(V_iV_j) = -\sqrt{p_i}\sqrt{p_j}$$ 
and that 
$$E(V_i^2)=1 - p_i$$
Now this is part of a proof I came upon and it is stated that $\mathbf{V}$ and $(Z_1,....,Z_r)$ have the same joint distribution without any further explanation. I have been trying to prove this for days now and I still can not come up with a reason why this is true (it is stated in the proof like an obvious fact but for it is not even obvious that $(Z_1,....,Z_r)$ have a jointly multinormal which is bothering me the most)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is only a partial answer to your question.

With the assumptions and information in your question, then $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_r)$ does not necessarily follow a multivariate normal distribution.

For a counterexample take $r = 2$ and $p_1 = p_2 = 1/2$. Let $Z_1\sim \mathcal N(0,1-p_1)$ and $Z_2 = -Z_1$ a.s.

This means that
$$
Z_2 \sim \mathcal N(0,1-p_2),
\\
\sum_i p_i = 1/2+1/2 = 1,
\\
E[Z_1Z_2] = -E[Z_1^2] = -(1-p_1) =  -1/2 = -\sqrt{p_1p_2}
$$
so all the requirements are fulfilled,
but clearly $(Z_1,Z_2) = (Z_1,-Z_1)$ does not follow a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but as I said I have seen as a part of a theorem, maybe I forgot some important assumption, my problem right now is that if this part of the proof is not true then I can not really trust the lecture notes I have been following lately, I will put now the link of the proof where I saw this if somebody wants to read it up 
http://studylib.net/doc/13587345/lecture-23-23.1-pearson%E2%80%99s-theorem.
page 91-92 (i.e. 2-3 in the  pdf file)

Comment: In your notes they show that the second moment and the covariance is the same for each index of the vectors (and imply that the first moment is also). Since the two vectors both have marginal normal distributions then $Z_i \stackrel d= V_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots,r$. This, however, is not necessarily enough to show that the two vectors $(Z_1,\ldots, Z_r)$ and $(V_1,\ldots, V_r)$ have the same joint distribution. It would be true if both vectors were multinormal distributions but as I showed in my answer, this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I would expect the result to be true but the proof seems incomplete to my expertise.