# Two sums of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Consider a sequence of $r$ normal random variables $Z_j\sim N(0,1-p_j)$ (where $\sum_{i=1}^r p_i =1$) such that $E(Z_iZ_j)=-\sqrt{p_jp_i}$. Now having another sequence of normal distributions such that $V_j\sim N(0,1-p_j)$ (where $\sum_{i=1}^r p_i =1$) such that $E(V_iV_j)=-\sqrt{p_jp_i}$. Now my question is, does it hold that $\sum_{i=1}^r Z_i$ is equally distributed as  $\sum_{i=1}^r V_i$ and does it hold taking squares i.e that 
$\sum_{i=1}^r Z_i^2$ is equally distributed as $\sum_{i=1}^r V_i^2$

Comment: If $Z_j$ are jointly distributed as multivariate normal (I have not check the validity of the covariances, but just assume they are valid at the moment), and you now provided all the means, variances, and covariances, then the distribution is completely characterized now as all the parameters are present. And similar for $V_j$. So if this assumption is true, then both random vector has the same distribution, and similar for their functions.

Comment: The problem is that the $Z_j$ are not know to be jointly multinormal,if they were then it would not be a problem proving this.My main problem was showing that the $Z_j$ have a multinormal distribution to complete a proof,but then that showed as very difficult since I could'n prove it, and I asked also here the question and I haven't gotten a very useful answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383923/equalitiy-of-two-multinormal-distributions) This was my way of trying to work around this problem of showing that they havea multinormal by showing equivalence of distributions of the sums